# Are QML calls to C++ public slots executed in the c++ target thread, or in QML (main thread)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qml

Imagine we have a QObject-based c++ class called `CppClass` that is registered in the QML context with the name `qmlCppClass` **and moved to a new thread** using `QObject::moveToThread("newThread* name")`.

Imagine `CppClass` has a **public slot** declared as `void doSomething()`.

Imagine the root **QML** object/window has a **signal** defined inside it called `signal()`.

Now assume 3 cases:

1. Inside my main.cpp (where I create the QML engine) I connect the signal() from QML to doSomething() in c++ in this way

```
    QObject::connect("QObject* cast of my QML engine", SIGNAL(signal()), "CppClass* object name", SLOT(doSomething()));
```

2. Inside my QML code, I write this inside the onClicked() slot in a button qml type:

```
    qmlCppClass.doSomething()
```

3. I use the Connections type in QML like this:

```
    Connections {
        target: qmlRoot
        function onSignal() {
            qmlCppClass.doSomething()
        }
    }
```

In each case, is the slot executed in the qml thread (a.k.a. main thread) or is it executed in the thread containing the `CppClass` object instance (a.k.a. target thread)?

Comment: Is this a theoretical question, or is this something that has occurred? Out of all the scenarios, I would suggest the first case is your best bet, since the QObject::connect() is thread safe meaning it takes care of marshalling all the arguments to the target thread. Whereas in cases 2 and 3, no such marshalling can occur, and, if anything, execution is implicitly in the QML Engine's thread hence it could be thread-unsafe and may lead to crashing.

Comment: @StephenQuan  It is something that I encounter a lot. I know that the first case is thread safe but it is hard to code, and also I read somewhere that the syntax in case 1 may become deprecated in the future. I also guess that case 2 is executed in the QML thread but I wanted to get other ppl's oponion about it. I am mostly curious about case 3 since it seems it wants to create a signal-slot connection :D

Comment: Another thing to consider is `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` is also thread-safe. If you have the `QObject*` passing it to QMetaObject::invokeMethod() would be themore reliable way to execute `doSomething()` in the right thread than to attempt to call it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `connect` is done with `QueuedConnection` then the slot will be executed on the receiver's thread, otherwise—on the sender's. Given you moved the receiver to another thread *before* making the connection, it would be a queued connection by default.

If there is no direct call to the `connect` function then `invokeMethod` might be used which has the same behavior as described above.

And if the direct call to a *member function* is used then it is executed in the thread where it is called from.

Comment: What about case 3? is it a direct call or a signal-slot connection?

Also, I read somewhere that Qt is moving away from the connect(name, SIGNAL(), name2, SLOT()) syntax and towards connect(name1, &class1::signal, name2, &class2::slot). If so, how should we create the signal-slot connections from QML to c++?

Comment: @Yasin case 3 is not different from case 2. You are creating a `Connections` object which resides in QML space and adding a slot `onSignal` (which belongs to the `Connections` object) which would be connected to the `signal` signal of the `qmlRoot` object.

Comment: @Yasin about your question regarding preferred syntax. I think it is not moving away, it has moved away long ago, it is just people are slow. But it is all about how you write connections in C++, it has nothing to do with QML.

Comment: The syntax matters because after QObject casting your QML object, its user-defined signals and slots (functions) will not be available to connect to using the new syntax. Also After some testing it seems that using case 2 and 3, the 'public slots' are executed in the destination thread while the 'public' functions are executed in the caller thread. Is that correct?

Comment: @Yasin of course syntax matters, you can't connect to a lambda with the old syntax. They are different but the new one is preferable. If you need to do something where only the new/old is used then you have no choice but use it. I still don't see how it has anything to do with QML, it is only about C++ code. And to the 2nd point: slot is a simple member function with a bit of presence in the meta-system thanks to MOC, there should be no difference of where it gets executed given you have the same way of calling them.